# Users reporting my GPS is not accurate in Android app

Tags: android, gps

I have users reporting my GPS is not the most accurate. I would like to know if somone could double check my code and let me know if I am missing something:

```
public class FindBrewery extends Fragment implements LocationListener, GetNearbyBreweries.OnArticleSelectedListener {

    private TextView latituteField;
    private TextView longitudeField;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        Context c = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        locationManager =(LocationManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    }



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //todo change view
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beer_location_list,container, false);

        // Get the location manager
        // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
        // default
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // Initialize the location fields
        if (location != null) {
            System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {

        }


        return rootView;
    }




    /* Request updates at startup */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    }

    /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
        //latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        //longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));

        //Toast.makeText(this, "Finding your loaction",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //call asycn task for location
        String url = "myURLWithLatAndLng";

        Log.d("urlTest", url);

        //async task goes here
        new GetNearbyBreweries(this.getActivity()).execute(url);

        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

        //todo: get json
        GetNearbyBreweries task = new GetNearbyBreweries(getActivity());
        task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(this);
        task.execute(url);



    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onArticleSelected(String b){

        //code to execute on click
        Fragment Fragment_one;
        FragmentManager man= getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();

        Fragment_one = new BreweryTabs();
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("breweryIDSent", b);
        Fragment_one.setArguments(bundle);
        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
        tran.addToBackStack(null);
        tran.commit();

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using getLastKnownLocation.  This will give you the last location it has (if it has any), which may not be up to date.  Instead you should use requestLocationUpdates or requestSingleUpdate to get the current location.  Also, you're using an uninitialized Criteria for provider.  That may get you GPS or NETWORK providers.  If you want GPS, request it explicitly.

Comment: Would coed like this be better:

http://www.androidsnippets.com/android-gps-location-with-listener

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in the manifest before application tag .. they may help..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
  -----

 </application>
```

Comment: Already have that in manifest. Sorry should have mentioned that.